# SQL Server 2005 how to iterate a CSV or table w/o cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return the email of users passed to my stored procedure. It's possible for multiple users to be passed into the stored procedure, separated by comma.

I have a split table value function I can use

```
INSERT INTO @stTbl  
   SELECT value   
   FROM fn_Split(@UFID , ',')
```

but the problem occurs when some values may not be in the table and I would need to insert the user from the CSV listing if not present in the user table.

I don't want to use a cursor, so whats the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO @stTbl (value)
SELECT value
FROM fn_Split(@UFID , ',') AS F
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM @stTbl AS T
  WHERE T.value = F.value
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL 2008, use the `MERGE` statement. It can be incredibly convenient.